# After updating the data of store in redux, this.props and nextProps are same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I updated `mainMenus` in first layer, it works well, but when I update the `sub_button` in second layer, I found that `this.props` and `nextProps` are same in `componentWillRecieveProps`（After updating `sub_button`, `sub_button` in `this.props` and `sub_button` in `nextProps` are same. `sub_button` is the latest in both of them）.

This is my data structure

```
CustomMenus: {
  mainMenus: [
   {
     name: "menu 1"
     sub_button: [
       {
         name: "sub menu 1"
       }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

this is my reducers

```
// update sub menus

case MOVE_SUB_MENU: {  
  let newCustomMenus = state.mainMenus ? [...state.mainMenus] : []
  let newSubMenus = [...newCustomMenus[action.mainMenuIndex].sub_button]
  if (action.to || action.to === 0) {
    newSubMenus.splice(action.to, 0, newSubMenus.splice(action.from, 1)[0])
    newCustomMenus[action.mainMenuIndex].sub_button = newSubMenus
  } else {
    newSubMenus.splice(action.from, 1)
    newCustomMenus[action.mainMenuIndex].sub_button = newSubMenus
  }
  return Object.assign({}, state, { mainMenus: newCustomMenus })
}

// update main menus

case MOVE_MAIN_MENU: {
  let newCustomMenus = state.mainMenus ? [...state.mainMenus] : []
  if (action.to || action.to === 0) {
    newCustomMenus.splice(action.to, 0, newCustomMenus.splice(action.from, 1)[0])
  } else {
    newCustomMenus.splice(action.from, 1)
  }
  return Object.assign({}, state, { mainMenus: newCustomMenus })
}
```

Is there anyone can help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need to use curly brackets inside `switch` statement. Also since you use spread syntax once, why don't you use it everywhere, incl. instead of `Object.assign`?

Comment: can you show how are you connecting props to state?, and action creators as well?

Comment: @hindmost: The array spread syntax and the object spread syntax are separate things - the former is in ES2015, the latter is still only a Stage 3 proposal and isn't yet part of the language spec. So they might just not have the Babel plugin for object spread installed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check `sub_button` in your code.

If you use log in your code, it will be easy to find problems when you are stock.

Example

```
case MOVE_SUB_MENU: {  
  let newCustomMenus = state.mainMenus ? [...state.mainMenus] : []
  let newSubMenus = [...newCustomMenus[action.mainMenuIndex].sub_button]

  console.log(newSubMenus);

  if (action.to || action.to === 0) {
    newSubMenus.splice(action.to, 0, newSubMenus.splice(action.from, 1)[0])
    newCustomMenus[action.mainMenuIndex].sub_button = newSubMenus
  } else {
    newSubMenus.splice(action.from, 1)
    newCustomMenus[action.mainMenuIndex].sub_button = newSubMenus
  }

  console.log(newSubMenus); // Check changed SubMenus
  console.log(newCustomMenus); // Check changed CustomMenus

  return Object.assign({}, state, { mainMenus: newCustomMenus })
}
```

Comment: `sub_button` looks like the `undefined`.  So I recommended to him/her to check code again. :)

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake. it's `sub_button`, I have updated the question

Comment: `sub_button` was updated successfully, but I don't know why `sub_button` in `this.props` and `nextProps` are same :)